# React:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, reactjs

```
var React = require('react');
var Recipe = require('../models/recipes.js').Recipe;
var IngredientCollection =require('../models/recipes.js').IngredientCollection;


var IngredientForm = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
var ingredients = new IngredientCollection();
ingredients.add([{}]);

return{
  ingredients: ingredients,
  recipe: new Recipe()
};
},
handleAmount: function(e){
var ingredients = this.state.ingredients;
this.props.ingredient.set('amount', e.target.value);
},
handleUnits: function(e){
var ingredients = this.state.ingredients;
this.props.ingredient.set('units', e.target.value);
},
handleName: function(e){
var ingredients = this.state.ingredients;
this.props.ingredient.set('name', e.target.value);
},
render: function(){
var ingredient = this.props.ingredient;

var count = this.props.counter + 1;
return (
  <div className="ingredients row">
    <h1 className="ingr-heading">Ingredients</h1>
   <div  className="ingredient-wrapper col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
       <input onChange={this.handleAmount} ref={"amount"}  type="text"  className="amount form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"/>
       <select onChange={this.handleUnits} ref={"units"} className="unit form-control" defaultValue="A">
         <option disabled value="A">unit</option>
         <option value="B">tsp.</option>
         <option value="C">tbsp.</option>
         <option value="D">fl oz(s)</option>
         <option value="E">cup(s)</option>
         <option value="F">pt(s)</option>
         <option value="G">qt(s)</option>
         <option value="H">gal(s)</option>
         <option value="I">oz(s)</option>
         <option value="J">lb(s)</option>
       </select>
       <input onChange={this.handleName} ref={"name"} type="text" className="ingr-place form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ingredient"/>
       <button id="submit-ingredient" type="button" className="btn btn-default">Add</button>
   </div>
 </div>

      // <div className="recipe-form">
      //   <form className="holding" onSubmit={this.handleNewRecipe}>
      //     <span className="make">Makes</span>
      //     <input type="text" className="servings" onChange={this.handleNameChange} ></input>
      //     <span className="how-many">Servings</span>
      //     <button className="btn btn-primary">Adjust Recipe</button>
      //   </form>
      // </div>

)
}
})
 var RecipeForm = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
 var ingredients = new IngredientCollection();
 ingredients.add([{}]);

return{
  ingredients: ingredients,
  recipe: new Recipe()
};
},
componentWillMount: function(){
var self = this;
var recipe = this.state.recipe;

recipe.on('change', this.update);
this.state.ingredients.on('add', this.update);
},
update: function(){
this.forceUpdate();
},
handleSubmit: function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var router = this.props.router;

var recipe = this.state.recipe;
var ingredients = this.state.ingredients;

recipe.set('ingredients', ingredients.toJSON());
console.log(recipe);

recipe.save().done(function(e){
  router.navigate('recipes/add', {trigger: true});
});
},
handleTitleChange: function(e){
this.state.recipe.set('title', e.target.value)
},
render: function(){
return(
  <form>
    <IngredientForm />
  </form>
)
}
})
module.exports = RecipeForm;
```

Im getting "cannot read property 'set' of undefined". I thought I did set it? I dont understand how else I am suppose to define it other than what Ive written so far. If anyone has any ideas please post, this is for a project that needs to be done soon!

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like you have not passed down an `ingredient` property from the parent. You may want to use [getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) to setup your `ingredient` property. Otherwise make sure you pass down an `ingredient` property when initializing the IngredientForm.

```
<IngredientForm ingredient={myIngredient}/>
```

Comment: IngredientForm being the parent?

Comment: Hey sorry maybe I used the wrong wording. I notice in `RecipeForm`, you initialize the `IngredientForm` but did not pass down an `ingredient` property. Right now `this.props.ingredient` is undefined in your `IngredientForm`.

Comment: hmm im still getting the same error message and i did:  <IngredientForm ingredient={ingredient} />

Comment: Based on your code snippet `ingredient` doesn't seem to be defined in your `RecipeForm` class. Based on what you posted it seems like only `recipe` and `ingredient` use the set method. I would really double check that they are not undefined. Be careful you are not mixing up `ingredient` and `ingredients`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your app is defined before the set method call or not.